# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal pop-up in footer OnScroll Event

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to find a fiddle or example on how to have a small modal pop-up in the footer area when a user scroll down the page. The modal I have in mind would be about 200px high and 100% wide with an email signup form. Would show up when the page is scrolled down and hide when it is back at the top. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using an alert rather than a modal.

check out [bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) which will give you the code to place an alert, then all you need to do is add some JS to get it to show on scroll, which would be simple enough if you wrap the alert in a Div.

You can place the input for signup in the alert popup, or a direct to a signup modal which contains the form :-)